# Database interaction using C# without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have been given an assignment where I need to display a form, data for which resides in various tables in Sql server. Requirement is strictly to not to use Entity framework or stored procedure. In such case, what are my options?

At the moment I am running some sql queries using SqlCommand object but then things are getting really complicated when it comes to fetching relational data and then allowing user to update it from the form.

What is the best way/approach in Winforms to allow view & edit of relational data?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Linq2Sql? Or can you just mess with your teacher and use NHibernate or another .net ORM?

Comment: Yes, just use SqlConnection/SqlCommand/SqlDataReader.

Comment: @NickBailey: If EF is prohibited it most probably means any ORM is prohibited.

Comment: There is a very short answer to your question. That is **ado.net**. Do you want to know anything else? If so add your code, ask specific questions about the problem you are having.

Comment: I assumed so, but I wanted to check because this instructor is asking people to use technology that was obsolete when MySpace was still popular, and deserves a commuppance.

Comment: There was no C# when myspace was popular...!!!

Comment: @KosalaW Myspace was founded in 2003.  C# was released in 2000.

Comment: "things are getting really complicated when it comes to fetching relational data and then allowing user to update it from the form" which is precisely why ORMs like Entity Framework were created.  You are on the right track with ADO.NET, but yes it can be tedious.

Comment: @DStanley I was being sarcastic because I do not see any advantage in giving this kind of assignments to students. If they want to teach students underlying technologies, they should start with a much lower level language and SQL please... not just linq. That's my opinion though.

Comment: @KosalaW Sorry, I misread your sarcasm. Still, I disagree - there's nothing wrong with teaching underlying technologies (even in C#) - people still teach arithmetic even though Siri can do your math for you.

Comment: @DStanley That example is a bit misleading though. :) You cannot compare teaching NET 1.1 and teaching arithmetic.

Comment: Linq To SQL will also count as Entity framework I guess, right? That leaves me with ADO.NET, or is there anything else?  Again I am not that familiar with ADO.NET so I am executing bunch of Sqls using Sqlcommand which is making things hard to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own simple classes for the objects you need to access / update.
For the purpose of the following example, let's assume you have 2 tables:

**Person**

- Person_Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
- Name NVARCHAR(100) NULL

**Emails**

- Person_Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
- Email_Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
- Email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

  ```
  public class MyProgram
  {

      public List<Person> ReadRecords()
      {
          // Set up your connection
          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
          conn.Open();

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person", conn);
          SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          List<Person> personRecords = new List<Person>();

          while (reader.Read())
          {
              Person p = new Person(reader, conn);
              personRecords.Add(p);
          }

          return personRecords;
      }

      public int UpdateRecords(IEnumerable<Person> records, SqlConnection conn)
      {
          int personsUpdated = 0;
          int recordsUpdated = 0;

          foreach (Person p in records)
          {
              if (p.Changed)
              {
                  recordsUpdated += p.Update(conn);
                  personsUpdated++;
              }
          }

          return recordsUpdated;
      }
  }

  public class Person
  {
      public const string SqlGetPersonEmailsCommand = "SELECT Email_Id, Email FROM Emails WHERE Person_Id = @Person_Id";
      public const string SqlUpdatePersonCommand = "UPDATE Person SET Name = @Name WHERE Id = @OriginalId";
      public const string SqlUpdatePersonEmailCommand = "UPDATE Emails SET Email = @Email WHERE Email_Id = @Email_Id";

      public int OriginalId { get; private set; }

      private bool personChanged;
      private bool emailsChanged { get { return changedEmails.Count > 0; } }
      public bool Changed { get { return personChanged || emailsChanged; } }

      private int _id;
      public int Id
      {
          get { return _id; }
          set
          {
              throw new Exception("Changing Id is not allowed.");
          }
      }

      private string _name;

      public string Name
      {
          get { return _name; }
          set
          {
              _name = value;
              personChanged = true;
          }
      }

      private List<int> changedEmails;
      private Dictionary<int, string> _emailAddresses;
      public string[] EmailAddresses
      {
          get
          {
              string[] values = new string[_emailAddresses.Count];
              _emailAddresses.Values.CopyTo(values, 0);
              return values;
          }
      }

      public void UpdateEmail(int emailId, string newEmail)
      {
          _emailAddresses[emailId] = newEmail;
          changedEmails.Add(emailId);
      }

      public Person(IDataReader reader, SqlConnection conn)
      {
          // Read ID (primary key from column 0)
          OriginalId = _id = reader.GetInt32(0);

          // Check if value in column 1 is Null; if so, set _name to Null, otherwise read the value
          _name = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(1);

          // Now get all emails for this Person record
          SqlCommand readEmailsCmd = new SqlCommand(SqlGetPersonEmailsCommand, conn);
          readEmailsCmd.Parameters.Add("@Person_Id", SqlDbType.Int);
          readEmailsCmd.Parameters["@Person_Id"].Value = OriginalId;

          SqlDataReader emailReader = readEmailsCmd.ExecuteReader();

          changedEmails = new List<int>();
          _emailAddresses = new Dictionary<int, string>();

          if (emailReader.HasRows)
          {
              while (emailReader.Read())
              {
                  int emailId = emailReader.GetInt32(0);
                  string email = emailReader.GetString(1);

                  _emailAddresses.Add(emailId, email);
              }
          }
      }


      public int Update(SqlConnection conn)
      {
          int rowsUpdated = 0;

          SqlCommand command = null;

          // Update Person record
          if (personChanged)
          {
              command = new SqlCommand(SqlUpdatePersonCommand, conn);

              command.Parameters.Add("@OriginalId", SqlDbType.Int);
              command.Parameters["@OriginalId"].Value = OriginalId;

              command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
              command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = _name;

              rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }

          // Now update all related Email records
          foreach (int id in changedEmails)
          {
              command = new SqlCommand(SqlUpdatePersonEmailCommand, conn);

              command.Parameters.Add("@Email_Id", SqlDbType.Int);
              command.Parameters["@Email_Id"].Value = id;

              command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
              command.Parameters["@Email"].Value = _emailAddresses[id];

              rowsUpdated = +command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }

          return rowsUpdated;
      }
  }
  ```

The above example supports changing the Person's name and associated email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In such case the best way by my opinion is to use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). You will be very close to ADO.NET and control all SQL queries. At the same time you will not spend time on mapping functionality - because this is quite simple, but time-consuming part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

- Question #1 is ends with "[besides Entity framework] what are my options?" and you got answers to that in the comments (Straight-up ADO.NET or NHibernate). You also know that because you said you're using a SqlCommand.
- Question #2 is the hard one and I think that is what your instructor wants you to find out: "What is the best way/approach in Winforms to allow view & edit of relational data?"

I do a ton of UI's for relational data using the Microsoft Stack. But regardless of technology, you need a good pattern or method. The short answer (that isn't a book) is to abstract the data from the UI. That way they can work independently and also change independently.

First realize editing data and displaying data should be two different parts of your program. One method I like is to select your relation data from SQL SERVER as XML, then use an XSLT to display it:

```
<Customer>
    <Name>...
    <Company>...
    <Phone>...
    <BillingAddresses>
         <Address>...
         <Address>...
    <PayementMethods>
         <CreditCard>...
         <CreditCard>...
    <RecentOrders>
         <Order>...
         <Order>...
         <Order>...
```

You can use an XSLT to easily make this into HTML that looks like whatever you want. In this example, next to where you display each `<Address>` and `<CreditCard>` you can put EDIT/DELETE links, along with a ADD links under each section.

Clicking EDIT/DELETE/ADD would take you to a screen to modify that part of the relational data. When you go back to the screen that displays the XML as HTML you would then see the updated data.

This is good because you can easily modify your XML without recompiling your code. You can also use the XSLT to display your data in whatever layout you want. Your XML can then include literals for what is stored as codes (AMX=AMERICAN EXPRESS, etc).

Anywho, this is just one solution with no real requirements (for example supporting "UNDO", applying several changes at once, etc.).

Comment: Thanks but focus here is primarily on C# & SQL. Using XML may give working solution but that is not what he is after. No third party tools like NHibernate allowed.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET is the best option you have for Database access. It's the technology EF is based on. To display data you use data binding most of the time. For saving and retrieving data you use ADO.NET. You probably don't want to bin ADO Objects directly to the UI but would have a view model instead. But traditionally and in the docs ASP.NET DataSets are often directly bound to the UI witch is from todays view a bad programming style.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Data set will be the best option. 
Procedure to use Data set 
1. Right click of your project, Go Add => New Item => Dataset. That is .xsd format file.
2. In that file right click inside the dataset, Agaign Add => Table Adapter. From that you need to complete your Data Connection after that select your table, start write your query.
3. once you finish creating you can directly connect your query to the class file.