# insert data to database c# WPF LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq

I am trying to make a bag room manager application to help manage the bag room at the golf course I work at. The project itself is a c# console Application. I am using WPF form the .NET framework. Currently, I am able to search through the database based off input from a search bar. I added a new window to be able to add a new player to the database. However, I am unfamiliar with LINQ to SQL so I am having a hard time with this portion of the process. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BagRoom.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BagRoom"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Bag Room Lookup" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="target" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="270,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
        <DataGrid Name="bagRoomGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="300" Margin="0,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="792"/>
        <Button Click="showTable" Content="Show Table" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Click="Window_Loaded" Content="Lookup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="525,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Click="addPlayer" Content="Add Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="345,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace BagRoom
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bagRoomEntities dataEntities = new bagRoomEntities();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string stringInput = target.Text;
            int numberInput = 0;

            //Is input a number????
            if (int.TryParse(stringInput, out numberInput))
            {
                var query =
                    from player in dataEntities.players
                    where player.bag_id == numberInput
                    orderby player.id
                    select new { player.id, player.first_name, player.last_name, player.bag_id };

                bagRoomGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
            }
            else 
            {
                    var query =
                        from player in dataEntities.players
                        where player.last_name == stringInput
                        select new { player.id, player.first_name, player.last_name, player.bag_id };

                    bagRoomGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
            }
        }
        

        //prints table to main window
        private void showTable(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var query =
               from player in dataEntities.players
               select new { player.id, player.first_name, player.last_name, player.bag_id };
               bagRoomGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }

        private void addPlayer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddPlayer addPlayerWindow = new AddPlayer();
            addPlayerWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

AddPlayer.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BagRoom.AddPlayer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BagRoom"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AddPlayer" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="fName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="336,65,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="First Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="264,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="lName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="336,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Bag Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="bagNum" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="336,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Click="insertPlayer" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="359,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

AddPlayer.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BagRoom
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AddPlayer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AddPlayer : Window
    {
        public AddPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void insertPlayer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string firstName = fName.Text;
            string lastName = lName.Text;
            int bagNumber;
            int.TryParse(bagNum.Text, out bagNumber);

            player newPlayer = new player();

            newPlayer.first_name = firstName;
            newPlayer.last_name = lastName;
            newPlayer.bag_id = bagNumber;

            //LINQ to SQL code to add player to database
            
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already settle on a database to use?

Comment: @pac0 yes I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Basically, you have two approaches. You can use an ORM (Object Relation Manager, like Entity Framework) to handle the interaction between some objects in your code and the DB. It could seems a bit overwhelming, there is much boilerplate code to write / add (look for a tutorial on a recent version of Entity Framework). You can also directly write SQL queries to your database. You can have a look here for a start (Serge's answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958249/database-interaction-using-c-sharp-without-entity-framework

Comment: also, as a side note: it seems your project is very simple and you are tempted to write all this interaction logic directly in your code-behind file that you showed us, but usually we consider a good practice to split _at least_ the "data access" (the part that communicates with the DB) part of the code from the rest.

Comment: In my first comment, I talked about the approaches you can have to save something to the db, but I forgot to actually give a strong sketch of answer: Linq to SQL are just extensions methods provided by an ORM (like Entity Framework) to facilitate the writing of the code. By itself, there is no "builtin Linq to SQL" methods in .NET, as far as I know, it's just a feature of some libraries.